# SharePoint : web service permission error

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, permissions, wss

I have a sharepoint site, and I am calling a standard sharepoint web service.

I create the web service request like this :

```
wsDws.Url = this.SiteAddress + @"/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx";
```

When I use localhost as hostname it works, but when I use machine name I get an error 401 Unauthorized.

I am setting the credentials like this:

```
    NetworkCredential NC;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Domain))
    {
        NC = new NetworkCredential(this.Username, this.Password);
    }
    else
    {
        NC = new NetworkCredential(this.Username, this.Password, this.Domain);
    }


    //Lists
    wsLists.Timeout = -1;
    wsLists.Credentials = NC;

    //Dws
    wsDws.Timeout = -1;
    wsDws.Credentials = NC;
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: did you have your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some settings in your registry to make it work. Quite annoying I know, but it does the trick:
http://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/access-denied-when-using-hostname-search-and-site-on-moss-2007/

Comment: Yup done that too, they offer 2 methods to resolve the issue - did both of them, and double checked to make sure it wasn't the loopbackcheck issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the infamous DisableLoopBackCheck problem. Get the solution and the reason [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861).